# Does Combine have publishers that only publish when a value actually changes?

Tags: swiftui, combine

Is there a way to make a `@Published` variable that only publishes its value when the new value is different from the old one?

Right now if we have

`@Published var test: Bool = false`

and we do

```
test = false
test = false
test = false
```

the publisher is called 3 times. This is quite annoying as it sometimes causes my SwiftUI Views to be recreated because somewhere higher up in the hierarchy a publisher was set to the value it previously was set, trough another publisher that was triggered (and that destroys text field inputs because view models through the hierarchy are recreated when that happens).

is there a way of only publishing when it goes from `false` to `true` or vice versa?

An example scenario:

We create a user object in our app, and we want to add a car to the user. The app should immediately show the "add car" view if no car is found, otherwise show the main application view. For that we have a listener somewhere. On our top level view we have:

```
    @ObservedObject var viewModel = UserViewModel()


    var body: some View {
            if !viewModel.hasVehicles {
                return AnyView(AddVehicleView(viewModel:AddVehicleViewModel())
            } else {
                return AnyView(UserMainView(user: user))
            }
        }
    }
```

in our `UserViewModel` we have

```
class UserViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var hasVehicles: Bool = false
```

- some code that updates that boolean when certain listeners trigger.

Inside `AddVehicleView` we have a form that allows the user to fill out some text fields and save the vehicle.

Now imagine that for some reason the code that updates the `hasVehicles` property is triggered, but there still are no vehicles. What happens:

`hasVehicles = false`

and the top level view is re-evaluated, resulting in `return AnyView(AddVehicleView(viewModel:AddVehicleViewModel())` being executed, and my form with text fields is emptied.

I suppose in this case I could solve it by putting `AddVehicleViewModel()` as a property inside the `View` struct, but that wouldn't solve it in the case when we want this to be executed multiple times, as that would mean next time the view gets built it will show the data of the last time we created that view, as we reuse the view model.

Comment: You should not worry about `@Published` publishing duplicates, it triggers the` View` to be reevaluated but not necessarily redrawn - that's where the diffing magic happens. Unfortunately you are using `AnyView` throwing all the diffing out. The best solution would be not to use `AnyView` and let `SwiftUI` do its work.

Comment: So what you are saying is that as soon as you start using AnyView, you get a redraw because SwiftUI considers it to be a new view?

Comment: If that is the case, how do you do a switch/if-else in your views that return 2 different view types, without resorting to AnyView?

Comment: Are you supporting iOS 13?

Comment: iOS14 only at the moment

Comment: If you wrap the whole switch in a `Group` -you should be able to remove `AnyView`

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that.

Comment: There's no reason to use a `Group`. Also, it doesn't make sense to call something a View View Model. It's only a View Model.

Answer (score 8):

Use Combine's `removeDuplicates()` operator in the code that updates the property. For example, the view model could create a publisher that updates a boolean property based on the value of two other boolean properties:

```
    @Published var hasTrucks: Bool
    @Published var hasCars: Bool
    @Published var hasVehicles: Bool

    func createVehiclePublisher() {
        Publishers.CombineLatest($hasTrucks, $hasCars)
            .map { $0 || $1 }
            .removeDuplicates()
            .assign(to: &$hasVehicles)
    }
```

Using `removeDuplicates()` causes `hasVehicles` to only be updated when there would be a change in its value.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use regular property with manual publisher activation, like

```
class UserViewModel: ObservableObject {
    var hasVehicles: Bool = false {
        willSet {
            if hasVehicles != newValue {
                objectWillChange.send()
            }
        }
    }
// ... other code
}
```

Comment: That seems like a feasible solution, but I can't imagine I am the only one running into these kinds of problems with the SwiftUI way of building an interface, once you have several layers of Views managing the screen? I was wondering if I missed something somewhere. A view should not be regenerated if the state controlling it didn't change value IMO.

Comment: @swiftPunk, it is not about arbitrary side-effect code, but about correctness of ObservableObject concept usage, which publisher as stated should be `objectWillChange`, ie. *before* object change.